# Oracle error 3113

Tags: visual-studio-2008, oracle10g

I'm developing a VS2008 desktop application, this application makes 2 connections, one to an access database and other to an oracle database. I can connect to both databases just fine but, when I'm trying to get a datatable from oracle, the application crashes throwing a ORA03113 error.This only happens when I call the Fill method of my OracleDataAdapter object.

I don't know how to fix this error, when I execute the same query in SQL Developer it works just fine.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I can't show you the connections string, but it can open a connection just fine.

The code is pretty standard:

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Dim info as Datatable = new Datatable
Dim adapter as OracleDataAdapter("Select * From userinfo ui Where ui.userid = 13", conn)
adapter.Fill(info)
```

The error shows up at `adapter.Fill()`

Comment: Courtesy of Mr. Google: http://dba-oracle.com/m_ora_03113_end_of_file_on_communications_channel.htm

Comment: I did find that, didnt solve anything, thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to try to run a query or something, but not the fill, and see it it crashes then? (figure out if its the fill or anyhting after the connect).

Comment: still crashes, the other queries run fine in SQL developer

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do not connect to the access database?  What happens if you use a different data table, such as DUAL, which has only a single row and single column named 'X'?

ORA-03113 is a catch-all "Well, I was connected but now I'm not" error.  http://dba-oracle.com/m_ora_03113_end_of_file_on_communications_channel.htm

Comment: I've tried both, with and without the access connection, nothing different happened, let me check that DUAL datatable thing.